# Similar function to Datenum of Matlab in R

Tags: r, matlab, datetime

I am working con time series and I need to convert from 1 January of 1988 to 31 December of 1988.

I know how to do it in Matlab using the function Datenum:

datenum_vect = datenum(year,1,1):datenum(year,12,31)

and the result is:

Columns 1 through 16

```
  726103      726104      726105      726106      726107
```

I try to use the Datenum function in R (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/solidearthtide/versions/1.0.2/topics/Datenum) but the library is not available for the last version of R 4.0.2.

Any idea in how to it in R obtaining the same values than for Datenum in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `ISOdate` giving `"POSIXct"`.

```
year <- 2020
ISOdate(year, 1, 1, 0)
# [1] "2020-01-01 GMT"
```

To get the Matlab value of numeric date, according to `?as.Date`, chapter "Conversion from other Systems", you need to convert `"POSIXct"` to `"date"` and add a constant.

```
as.numeric(as.Date(ISOdate(1988, 1, 1, 0))) + 719529
# [1] 726103
```

`as.numeric(ISOdate(.))` gives seconds; therefore additionally we need `as.Date()` to get days.

Comment: But how I pass from  1988-01-01 GMT to numeric? I tried: year <- 1988; t <- ISOdate(year, 1, 1, 0); 
as.numeric(t), but the result is 567993600, not  726103 as in Matlab for 1 January 1988